# How to get ActionBarSize in Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

How can I get the ActionBarSize in Jetpack Compose?

In xml is: `?android:attr/actionBarSize`

Comment: You don't need the action bar's size when using Jetpack Compose. Please include your code and why you think you need this so we can prevent an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: The size of your toolbar is whatever you decide it should be using `Modifier.size` on your toolbar composable.

Comment: Better use TopAppBar